# SQL where subquery not filtering like expected

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a SQL query as below. What I want with the where part is for the result to not return rows where CategorySite returns more than two rows with the matched categoryid in ProductCategory regardless of SiteId. The problem is that I know that ProductCategory has more than one matching categories for some of the results I am receiving, so there is something wrong with my query and I can't figure out what.

```
select top 10 pp.*
from ProductProperty pp 
inner join ProductCategory pc on pp.fkProductId = pc.fkProductId and pp.fkLocaleId = 1
inner join CategorySite cs on pc.fkCategoryId = cs.fkCategoryId and cs.fkSiteId = 2
inner join CategoryProperty cp on cs.fkCategoryId = cp.fkCategoryId and cp.fkLocaleId=1  
where (select count(*) from CategorySite css where pc.fkCategoryId = css.fkCategoryId) = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to do this using my intial solution, turns out the problem was elsewhere. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you joining `CategoryProperty` if you don't use it in the predicate?

try this. If you need CategoryProperty, try adding it at the end

```
;WITH InsteadOfWhere AS 
(
    SELECT fkCategoryId 
    FROM CategorySite 
    GROUP BY fkCategoryId 
    HAVING COUNT(fkCategoryId) = 1 

)
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM ProductProperty pp 
inner join ProductCategory pc on pp.fkProductId = pc.fkProductId and pp.fkLocaleId = 1
INNER JOIN InsteadOfWhere ON InsteadOfWhere.fkCategoryID = pc.fkCategoryId 
inner join CategorySite cs on InsteadOfWhere.fkCategoryId = cs.fkCategoryId and cs.fkSiteId = 2
```

Comment: I got some strange results from this actually, not sure what was going on. I've solved my problem but thanks a lot anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

A good approach for this is the window functions.  You can calculate the count in a subquery and then do the select that you want:

```
select t.*
from (select pp.*,
             count(*) over (partition by pc.fkCategoryId) as cnt
      from ProductProperty pp 
      inner join ProductCategory pc on pp.fkProductId = pc.fkProductId and pp.fkLocaleId = 1
      inner join CategorySite cs on pc.fkCategoryId = cs.fkCategoryId and cs.fkSiteId = 2
      inner join CategoryProperty cp on cs.fkCategoryId = cp.fkCategoryId and cp.fkLocaleId=1
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

I am assuming the database is SQL Server (or perhaps Sybase) based on the syntax.  Both support window functions.

Comment: I got the same result as the above from this so this works quite well too (as it turns out my problem was elsewhere).